# R Pi as web server for Code Igniter

Tags: web-server

Im trying to use R Pi 2 as web server for a simple system created using CodeIgniter. I was able to install LAMP, php7, mysql, phpmyadmin. Localhost shows the installation was successful. I tried to copy the CI app to /var/www/html through Filezilla but the nothing is transferred after a long series of error messages. I also tried to manually create a folder inside /var/www/html through Filezilla but the mkdir operation is denied. How should I go about this? Should I copy the entire CI app to /var/www/html or should it be somewhere else. I've been searching for videos/tutorials regarding installation of CI app in R Pi but still unlucky to find one. Is it really possible to use R Pi to host an app created using Codeigniter? I hope someone who has done this before can offer help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the error messages. You may post them on pastebin.com. To create that folder manually, try `sudo mkdir [DirectoryName]`

Answer (score -1):

You may have additional problems, but first in line seems to be that you need to use `sudo` to write into directories under `/var/www` unless you've made modifications to the permission or to the groups that your user is in.  So, for example, `sudo mkdir /var/www/test/`.